# How do I listen to hardware keyboard inputs in React-Native Android

Tags: android, react-native

There is a login page(`login.js`) in my React-Native project. `login.js` has two `TextInput` and a `Button`. When I finished entering the account number and password, I press **Enter** 
 key on the hardware keyboard, the `Button` is auto focused and trigger login. But I do not want the `Button` auto focused after pressing **Enter**, I want to trigger login when the user press the `Button`. What can I do to disable the **Enter** key on the hardware keyboard?

```
<View style={styles.field}>
  <Text style={_label}>Account</Text>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.value}
    defaultValue={account}
    keyboardType="phone-pad"
    underlineColorAndroid={Color.borderHue}
    onChangeText={this.handleChangeAccount.bind(this)} />
</View>
<View style={styles.field}>
  <Text style={_label}>Password</Text>
  <TextInput
    style={styles.value}
    defaultValue={password}
    underlineColorAndroid={Color.borderHue}
    secureTextEntry
    onChangeText={this.handleChangePassword.bind(this)} />
</View>
<Button
  style={styles.loginBtn}
  onPress={this.login.bind(this)}>
  Login
</Button>
```

Comment: Did you use the `onKeyPress` or `onSubmitEditing`?

Comment: share the code so that we can help you.

Comment: @PhanSinh on Android only the inputs from soft keyboard are handled, not the hardware keyboard inputs.

Comment: @afishhhhh You mean the keyboard in the computer of emulator?

Comment: @PhanSinh No, the physical keyboard in a scanner

Answer (score 0):

Try using preventDefault():

preventDefault() is called on the event when submitting the form to prevent a browser reload/refresh.

```
onKeyPress(event) {
    if (event.which === 13 /* Enter */) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
},
render() {
  return (
      <Input onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} ...
...
```

For more, here you have the issue from Git: https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/issues/360

Comment: That's only applicable for React in a browser - not React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution

```
// ...
render() {
  return (
    <TextInput 
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordRef.focus()}
    />
    <TextInput 
      ref={ref => this.passwordRef = ref} 
    />
  );
}
// ...
```

For more, here you have the issue from this link https://davidtranscend.com/blog/focus-next-input-react-native/